# Disable Caching in HTML5 boilerplate

Tags: jquery, html, caching, html5boilerplate

HTML5 boilerplate is currently being used on a site that I'm working on. I'm in the process of developing my site and having to clear the browser's cache now and then is slowing down my development speed.

Javascript files seem to be cached and I suspect its due to one of the configuration in html5 boilerplate. How should I disable the caching?

Comment: If you're running an apache server check the .htaccess near `Expires headers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site is using the .htaccess file as distributed in the HTML5 boilerplate package, edit the line

```
ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
```

so that you replace `1 year` by `0 seconds` in your development environment.